# Python 3: Add Enum attributes to class scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

In Python 3.10+ is there a way to add the attributes (`RED` in this case) to the scope of a class (`MyClass` in this case) like this:

```
    class Color(Enum):
        RED = 1
    class MyClass():
        def myMethod(self, t):
            return t is RED # instead of return t is Color.RED
```

Without

1. adding `RED` to the global scope e.g. like this: `globals().update(Color.__members__)`
2. adding some initialization code to every class method (e.g. like the above; but `locals()` cannot be updated in that fashion anyway as far as I know)

Comment: What exactly is the use-case here?

Comment: Also, the proper way to compare Enum values is using `is` not `==` so you'd use `return t is Color.RED` instead of `return t == Color.RED`

Comment: You're right of course.

Answer (score 0):

You must use this sintax:

enum_class.enum => Color.RED

I also found this in Python's doc:

> Comparisons against non-enumeration values will always compare not equal (again, IntEnum was explicitly designed to behave differently)
>
> Color.BLUE == 2 => False

You must use IntEnum.

```py
from enum import IntEnum

class Color(IntEnum):
    RED = 1
    
class MyClass():
    def myMethod(self, t):
        return Color.RED == 1 # Use 'enum_class.enum' to access to your attribute

print(MyClass().myMethod(1)) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the pythonic way:

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1

class MyClass():

    RED = Color.RED

    def my_method(self, t):
        return t is self.RED
```

Also, you can make `my_method` a `@classmethod`.

When the `RED` attribute is bound to the class like this, it also plays nicely with inheritence. E.g. subclasses can override it.

The following is more in line with your question, yet less recommended IMO:

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1

RED = Color.RED

class MyClass():
    def my_method(self, t):
        return t is RED
```

Comment: Do you think this could be achieved without the reference to ```self``` or the class name?

Comment: Sure, make a global variable, by assiging `RED = Color.RED` in the global scope. However, as explained in the answer, there are advantages to binding it to the class.

Comment: Is it possible to mixin the ```Color``` class into ```MyClass``` like ```class MyClass(Color):``` to achieve the same effect saving the code to declare the aliases (```RED = Color.RED```)

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea. Please expalin more about your specific use case and why you want to do that.

Comment: That was just out of curiosity to save some code - the enumeration might be quite large.

Comment: Instead of the explicit assignment, you can do `MyClass.__dict__.update(Color.__members__)`. Still need the `self.` prefix when accessing the attribute.

Comment: @Waschbaer: If you want to save typing, just make a short alias: `_E = EnumWithAnUncomfortablyLongName`, for example, and then you can write `_E.whatever` instead of `EnumWithAnUncomfortablyLongName.whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no class scope. Classes have a namespace, but no other code can access it automatically and directly, they always must access it via the class name, or via `self` inside a method.

If you added `RED` as a class variable, you'd need to use either `MyClass.RED` or `self.RED` in the method, which doesn't seem much better than accessing it via `Color`.